# Android Camera Preview Rotation

Tags: android, orientation, android-camera

According to Android Developer Site:

after android 2.2 there is the function

" setDisplayOrientation "

to adjust the camera preview rotation.

And also according to the Android Developer Site , we can find following source code.

```
android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
            new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degrees = 0 ;
    switch ( rotation ) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0 : degrees = 0 ; break ;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90 : degrees = 90 ; break ;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180 : degrees = 180 ; break ;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270 : degrees = 270 ; break ;
    }
    int result ;
    if ( info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = ( info.orientation + degrees ) % 360 ;
         result = ( 360 - result ) % 360 ;   // compensate the mirror
    } else {   // back-facing

        result = ( info.orientation - degrees + 360 ) % 360 ;

    }
```

However, i can not work with some kind of Devices.
Like Samsung Galaxy Y S5360, S5660 , YP-G1, YP-G70, etc

Just part of machine not working, Galaxy Nexus, SII , or some high end device, it work fine.

Does setDisplayOrientation not support , or the devices firmware is not ready?

PS. All devices are Android 2.3.1 or above.

Help.

Comment: I'm facing same issue on my Galaxy Y. Did you find out something? I'd like to know at least if setDisplayOrientation succeeded, to lock it to landscape if not.

Comment: at last, not solved. just make the camera surface activity to horizontal view.

Comment: Does anyone have a list of devices that this error occurs on?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The problem of setting the orientation display of camera doesn't work on operating system version of these devices that is basically the (gingerbread) but for the devices above this it works fine .

I tried this too on these devices the landscape mode works fine but portrait mode has the problem. In case to force to portrait just forced the camera orientation to 90 degrees
through this in

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
    int height) {

camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);


}
```

as well as did post rotate the picture before displaying or saving it through
in

```
    PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback(){


     public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {

    Bitmap bitmapPicture= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length);
      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
     matrix.postRotate(90);
     int height=bitmapPicture.getHeight();
     int width=bitmapPicture.getWidth();
     Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapPicture,height,width, true);
      Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap , 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

HOPE THIS HELPS

Answer (score -3):

Try set orientation of your camera view's xml to landscape.

Comment: Not a really helpful answer if the OP would wan't landscape he wouldn't ask how to get portrait in the first place.

Comment: @Shirkrin the answer looks weird at first place. But the fact is, in some devices, the preview of camera is fixed to landscape. If you adjust the xml of your camera preview to landscape, it will fit all the device. What you'll do next is to use matrix to rotate the picture taken by camera.