# How to manage the front camera orientation in Android when video recording?

Tags: android, video, android-orientation, video-recording

I'm trying to develop a camera recorder app in portrait mode. When I record a video with the back camera, the video has the properly orientation because it do the right rotations. But, when I try to show the preview with the front camera, in some devices it works fine, but in others the video has a rotation of 180º like HTC Desire. So, how to control this problem to rotate the camera in right position?

UPDATE: I've found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426230/android-camera-recording-video-but-plays-upside-down) which explains my problems, and the solutions are to re-encode the video, to develop an playback activity that understands the metadata or to upload the video to the server and rotate it. My best solution will be develop a new playback video in my application. Could someone give me some guidelines? Is necesary to use the ffmpeg library? I've developed a basic playback video, but how can I orientate the video using the metadata?

```
private boolean initCamera() {
    try {
        camera  = getCameraInstance(selected_camera);

        Camera.Parameters camParams = camera.getParameters();
        camParams.set( "cam_mode", 1 );
 //            camParams.set("orientation", "portrait");

        checkCameraFlash(camParams);

        setAngleCameraRotation();
 //            camera.setDisplayOrientation(angle_rotation_camera);

        setAspectResolutionCamera(camParams);

        camera.setParameters(camParams);

        video_view.getHolder().setFixedSize(height_video, width_video);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(height_video, width_video);
        video_view.setLayoutParams(lp);

        camera.lock();

        surface_holder = video_view.getHolder();
        surface_holder.addCallback(this);
        surface_holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        setPreviewCamera();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.v("RecordVideo", "Could not initialize the Camera");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void initCameraRecorder() {

    if(media_recorder != null) return;

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    output_file_name = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + File.separator + timeStamp + ".mp4";

    File outFile = new File(output_file_name);
    if(outFile.exists()) {
        outFile.delete();
    }

    try {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.unlock();
        media_recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        media_recorder.setCamera(camera);

        media_recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        media_recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
        profile.videoBitRate = 885000;              //Medium quality
        profile.videoFrameHeight = height_video;
        profile.videoFrameWidth = width_video;
        media_recorder.setProfile(profile);

        media_recorder.setMaxDuration(21000);       // limit to 21 seconds
        media_recorder.setOrientationHint(setOrientationCameraRecorder());
        media_recorder.setPreviewDisplay(surface_holder.getSurface());
        media_recorder.setOutputFile(output_file_name);

        media_recorder.prepare();
        Log.v("RecordVideo", "MediaRecorder initialized");

    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.v("RecordVideo", "MediaRecorder failed to initialize");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Camera getCameraInstance(int camera_id) {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(camera_id); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

 private void setAspectResolutionCamera(Parameters camParams) {
    float aspect_ratio = 1f;
    int aspect_width = 2000, aspect_height = 2000;
    List<Size> supported_sizes_list = camParams.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    for (int i = 0; i < supported_sizes_list.size(); i++) {
        Size size = supported_sizes_list.get(i);
        if (Math.abs(VIDEO_ASPECT_RATIO - (float) size.height / size.width) <= aspect_ratio ) {
            if (Math.abs(VIDEO_ASPECT_WIDTH - size.height) <= aspect_width) {
                if (Math.abs(VIDEO_ASPECT_HEIGHT - size.width) < aspect_height) {
                    width_video = size.width;
                    height_video = size.height;
                    aspect_ratio = Math.abs(VIDEO_ASPECT_RATIO - (float) size.height / size.width);
                    aspect_width = Math.abs(VIDEO_ASPECT_WIDTH - size.height);
                    aspect_height = Math.abs(VIDEO_ASPECT_HEIGHT - size.width);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


/** Sets the angle camera rotation. It's the user sees */
private void setAngleCameraRotation() {
    Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(selected_camera, info);       // back-facing camera
    int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
    }
    angle_rotation_camera = (info.orientation - degrees) % 360;  // back-facing camera rotation
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/39271585/1495839
You can find solution