# Bitmap dimensions using camera (custom view)

Tags: android, camera, landscape-portrait

I'm developing for API 7 (2.1). I implemented a camera view like this:

```
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
SurfaceHolder mHolder;

int width;
int height;

Camera mCamera;

public CameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initHolder();
}

public CameraView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initHolder();
}

private void initHolder() {
    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where to
    // draw.
    mCamera = Camera.open();

//      Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
//      // If we aren't landscape (the default), tell the camera we want
//      // portrait mode
//      if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
//          params.set("orientation", "portrait"); // "landscape"
//          // And Rotate the final picture if possible
//          // This works on 2.0 and higher only
//          // params.setRotation(90);
//          // Use reflection to see if it exists and to call it so you can
//          // support older versions
//          try {
//              Method rotateSet = Camera.Parameters.class.getMethod("setRotation", new Class[] { Integer.TYPE });
//              Object arguments[] = new Object[] { new Integer(90) };
//              rotateSet.invoke(params, arguments);
//          } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
//              // Older Device
//              Log.v("CAMERAVIEW", "No Set Rotation");
//          } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
//              Log.v("CAMERAVIEW", "Exception IllegalArgument");
//          } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
//              Log.v("CAMERAVIEW", "Illegal Access Exception");
//          } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
//              Log.v("CAMERAVIEW", "Invocation Target Exception");
//          }
//      }
//      mCamera.setParameters(params);
    setDisplayOrientation(mCamera, 90);

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
    // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
    // important to release it when the activity is paused.
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    width = w;
    height = h;
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin the preview.
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    //parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

    mCamera.startPreview();
}

public void takePicture(Camera.ShutterCallback shutter, Camera.PictureCallback raw, Camera.PictureCallback jpeg) {
    mCamera.takePicture(shutter, raw, jpeg);
}

protected void setDisplayOrientation(Camera camera, int angle){
    Method downPolymorphic;
    try {
        downPolymorphic = camera.getClass().getMethod("setDisplayOrientation", new Class[] { int.class });
        if (downPolymorphic != null) {
            downPolymorphic.invoke(camera, new Object[] { angle });
        }

    } catch (Exception e1) {}
}
}
```

Only the approach using reflection (taken from Williew's answer in [Android camera rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309029/android-camera-rotate)) works on my device to show the preview with the correct rotation, otherwise, the preview is always rotated -90°

So far so good, but now I have another problem. When I get the bitmap with the activitie's callback:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

    Log.d("test", "---width: "  + b.getWidth() + " height: " + b.getHeight());
}
```

It's always in landscape mode! (in this case 2560 x 1920). So if the user took a picture holding the device in portrait mode, I get a bitmap 2560 x 1920, which anyways, for some reason looks exactly like the portrait pic I took, when I put in in an image view. Problem comes when the user takes the pic holding the device in landscape mode, I would like to rotate it, in order to show the result in portrait mode (scaled down) - or do some other special actions for landscape pics.

But I can't differentiate them from the portrait pics because the bitmap's dimensions are the same :/

How do I recognize portrait / landscape pictures?

Any idea...? I'm new to the camera and kind of lost...
Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
Ok, I think there's no problem, with the dimensions always being the same, because the picture has actually always the same dimensions, no matter how I was holding the device. Only thing I don't understand is why I always get width > height when the preview and the pics are clearly in portrait mode.

Comment: You should probably just detect in which ORIENTATION mode you are?http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation or getResources().getConfiguration().orientation

Comment: App runs in portrait, orientation is always portrait.