# Open the Front facing camera by default not working

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I found this hack,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
```

from [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202416/intent-to-take-video-in-android). Apparently the Front camera worked for the person. But this does not work on my Moto G. Is there any other hack except Building our own custom camera app to achieve this.

Following is my code.:

```
Intent takeVideoIntent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
if (noOfCameras>1){
 Log.d("It came here", "it came here");
 takeVideoIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING",      Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
 }
            if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
                startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent,1);
                //1 is for video capture;
            }
        }
    });
```

Am i doing something wrong. I could not comment on the mentioned SO link since don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I thing , its not possible through Camera Intent.You need to create   your camera Surfaces.(Waiting for other Answers).

Comment: There is no requirement for any camera app to necessarily honor that extra.

Comment: Okay, is there no other possibility except customizing the camera app.