# Alternative to android camera api

Tags: android, android-camera

Is there any other way to have a stable and reliable camera preview that works on all devices?

Android camera preview has given me a headache with the error reports I get from users.

The rotation and size of screen are different on each device which leads to many errors.

Comment: For rotate check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309029/android-camera-rotate